# Is this an application case of Bayes theorem? Is my book wrong?

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem

A sickness has a heterozygote frequency of $\frac{1}{20}$ ie. 1 in 20 people of a population will have the allele combination $Aa$ where a denotes the recessive and A the dominant allele. To become sick the carrier needs to have two $aa$ alleles.

A mother is known to have the combination $Aa$ , what is the probability her child will be sick (have $aa$) if the combination of the husband is unknown (i.e. $AA, Aa, aa)$?

Now here is where I struggle. If the husband has $AA$ , the child will never get $aa$, if the husband has $Aa$, the child will get $aa$ with a chance of $\frac{1}{4}$.

If the husband has $aa$ (is sick himself) then the child wil get $aa$ with a chance of $\frac{1}{2}$

The book states that the answer a priori is for the child to be sick in this situation is $\frac{1}{20} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{80}$

Shouldn't it instead  be : $\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{20} + (\textbf{double aa frequency})\cdot \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Maybe the implication is that if the husband's combination is unknown, it must mean that he does not have $aa$, since he would have shown symptoms already?  Is the "(i.e., $AA, Aa, aa$)" yours, or the book's?

Comment: mine, and your answer makes a lot of sense lol, but my assumption is correct if aa was included ?

Comment: actually i rechecked, and the book doesnt say anything about the husband showing early symptoms, it just says that the probability a priori is what i wrote in my post (1/80)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know.  Is the book online by any chance?

Comment: no and its not in english lol, do you know if my attempt is correct? can you just sum the two probability trees together?

Comment: If I understand the problem, yes.  It's not Bayes, it's just total probability.

Comment: do you think it could be because the probability of somebody having aa is very small, it was just left out intentionally? the chance of somebody having aa is 1:3000

Comment: I suppose it's possible.  Without knowing how rigorous they're trying to be, it's hard for me to say whether they're treating it as negligible or not.

Comment: Thanks man, wish i could upvote you for your answers.

Comment: No worries!  I think you've got the basic idea.

Comment: I feel bad for the book. If there was anything, it should have been a "typo" or an "errata" rather than a wrong book :)

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that the father could be AA, Aa, or aa. What we need to remember is that these represent the alleles he received from his parents. So, if we let the first letter represent the allele received from his father and the second letter represent the allele gained from his mother, there are actually four possibilities: AA, Aa, aA, aa. That is, the father has a 1/4 chance of being either AA or aa, but a 2/4 = 1/2 chance of being Aa.

When these are combined with the known Aa of the mother, you will see that there are 4 of 16 possibilities resulting in aa. Thus, the probability of being aa are 1/4 ... and if 1/20 of those have the disease, then the result is 1/80.